# Spacer does not create any space

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a profile screen for the user and i want to put a **Spacer** below the ***Save Changes*** button to create some space between this button and the 2 other buttons below it (logout, and change password), but for some reason the Spacer does not create any space between the buttons. I tried doing this using a simple **sizedBox** but i want my app to be responsive so i can't use this "solution".

Can anyone help me? :)

**My Build widget:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF263238),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset(
                          "assets/images/back_icon.png",
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                        iconSize: 40,
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Go to previews screen
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, top: 12),
                      child: const Text(
                        "My Profile",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 23),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Spacer()
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 10),
                  child: isProfilePictureEmpty
                      ? _emptyProfilePicture(context)
                      : _profilePictureFromURL(context),
                ),
                Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 45.0, right: 40.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: const [
                              Text("Username",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 17)),
                              Spacer()
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 72, 92, 105)),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 5.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            controller: usernameController,
                            onChanged: (usernameInput) {
                              setState(() {
                                username = usernameInput;
                                isSaveButtonEnabled = true;
                              });
                            },
                            cursorColor: Colors.black,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                                hintText: "Username"),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
                Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 45.0, right: 40.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: const [
                              Text("Email address",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 17)),
                              Spacer()
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 72, 92, 105)),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 5.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            controller: emailController,
                            onChanged: (emailInput) {
                              setState(() {
                                email = emailInput;
                                isSaveButtonEnabled = true;
                              });
                            },
                            cursorColor: Colors.black,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                                hintText: "Email address"),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                  width: 370,
                  height: 50,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed:
                        !isSaveButtonEnabled ? null : _saveProfileChanges,
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        primary: Colors.indigo),
                    child: Text("$saveButtonText",
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  ),
                ),

                const Spacer(),
                
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                  width: 370,
                  height: 50,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        primary: Colors.indigo),
                    child: const Text("Change password",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                  width: 370,
                  height: 50,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      CoolAlert.show(
                        onConfirmBtnTap: logout,
                        onCancelBtnTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        context: context,
                        type: CoolAlertType.confirm,
                        text: 'Do you want to logout?',
                        confirmBtnText: 'Yes',
                        cancelBtnText: 'No',
                        confirmBtnColor: Colors.red,
                      );
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        primary: Colors.red),
                    child: const Text("Logout", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  ),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                const Spacer(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 16, 8, 16),
          child: Text(
            "Made by George Sepetadelis",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: you can not use `Spacer` inside scrollable widgets. you are using `Spacer` inside `ListView`. It will through and error.

Comment: You are using widgets incorrectly. Please use Column instead of ListView. To make spacer work, you need to define height of containers and the also give height to the main container too.

Comment: * [Row] and [Column], which are the most common containers to use a Spacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using 'CustomScrollView' widget, you can implement what you want.

[image]

[image]

I removed some callback function body and condition state code because of lack of your code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF263238),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                  [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Image.asset(
                              "assets/images/back_icon.png",
                              height: 30,
                              width: 30,
                            ),
                            iconSize: 40,
                            onPressed: () {
                              // Go to previews screen
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, top: 12),
                          child: const Text(
                            "My Profile",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 23),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Spacer()
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 10),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 45.0, right: 40.0),
                            child: Row(
                              children: const [
                                Text("Username",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 17)),
                                Spacer()
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 72, 92, 105)),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 5.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              // controller: usernameController,
                              onChanged: (usernameInput) {
                                // setState(() {
                                //   username = usernameInput;
                                //   isSaveButtonEnabled = true;
                                // });
                              },
                              cursorColor: Colors.black,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                  errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                  disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                                  hintText: "Username"),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 45.0, right: 40.0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: const [
                                  Text("Email address",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 17)),
                                  Spacer()
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  color:
                                      const Color.fromARGB(255, 72, 92, 105)),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                // controller: emailController,
                                onChanged: (emailInput) {
                                  // setState(() {
                                  //   email = emailInput;
                                  //   isSaveButtonEnabled = true;
                                  // });
                                },
                                cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                    errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 15,
                                        bottom: 11,
                                        top: 11,
                                        right: 15),
                                    hintText: "Email address"),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )),
                    const SizedBox(height: 30),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                      width: 370,
                      height: 50,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            primary: Colors.indigo),
                        child: Text("saveButtonText",
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SliverFillRemaining(
                hasScrollBody: false,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                      width: 370,
                      height: 50,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            primary: Colors.indigo),
                        child: const Text("Change password",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40),
                      width: 370,
                      height: 50,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          // CoolAlert.show(
                          //   onConfirmBtnTap: logout,
                          //   onCancelBtnTap: () {
                          //     Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          //   },
                          //   context: context,
                          //   type: CoolAlertType.confirm,
                          //   text: 'Do you want to logout?',
                          //   confirmBtnText: 'Yes',
                          //   cancelBtnText: 'No',
                          //   confirmBtnColor: Colors.red,
                          // );
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            primary: Colors.red),
                        child: const Text("Logout",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 16, 8, 16),
          child: Text(
            "Made by George Sepetadelis",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```